# Appium cannot search element by resource id

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I have trying to create a automation script for an android application using appium. I am trying to select an element and perform a click operation using the following code.

```
MobileElement loginElt = (MobileElement)driver.findElementById("ca.*******.bond:id/menu_item_sign_in");
```

Where `ca.********.bond:id/menu_item_sign_in` is the resource id.

The problem is that appium is not able to search for the resource id although it is available via the uiautomator.

Comment: Just add `.click();
  driver.findElementById("ca.bellmedia.cravetv.bond:id/menu_item_sign_in").click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `.click();`

and eliminate the app ID

```
driver.findElementById("menu_item_sign_in").click();
```